# How to calculate next point given two gps coordinates and speed?

Tags: python, gps, coordinates, python-2.7

If an entity is traveling in a straight line and at a known speed of 1km/min, how can I calculate the next point at time t given two gps locations? The altitude does not matter. The gps format is in EPSG:4326.

Can someone provide an example in python? It's not as simple as finding the slope of a line, like how we learned in algebra class?

Comment: If you can project the points onto a plane, it could be as simple as finding the slope. Can you project the geographic coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

You know the location of point A and point B so you can use trigonometry to calculate the direction of travel.  You know the times at point A and point B so you can calculate the speed of travel.  Create a Euclidean Distance surface around point B such that each cell size represents one time unit of measure (one cell = one second of travel?).  Create a Euclidean Direction surface around point B.  Select that cell that has the correct direction and distance.  You can do most of this in Modelbuilder, then export your model to Python if you need to.